# Cannot find module 'xmlbuilder' when trying to run Production version of Electron Project

Tags: npm, electron

I have an electron program I am building to production. When I run the .exe created I get the following error.

[image: Error Loading my Electron Program]

I have installed xmlbuilder using the following command

npm install -g xmlbuilder

Here is my package.json file as well.

```
    {
  "name": "Title Of Program Here",
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "description": " ",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "package-mac": "electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/mac/icon.icns --prune=true --out=release-builds",
    "package-win": "electron-packager . electron-tutorial-app --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=assets/icons/win/icon.ico --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\" Title \"",
    "package-linux": "electron-packager . electron-tutorial-app --overwrite --asar=true --platform=linux --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/png/icon.png --prune=true --out=release-builds"
  },
  "author": "David Klecker",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "ejs": "^3.1.2",
    "electron": "^8.2.0",
    "electron-alert": "^0.1.5",
    "electron-reload": "^1.5.0",
    "embed-js": "^5.0.4",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jquery-treegrid": "^0.3.0",
    "php-server-manager": "^1.3.3",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "python-shell": "^1.0.8",
    "uniter": "^2.14.0",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ejs-lint": "^1.1.0",
    "electron-packager": "^14.2.1",
    "xmlbuilder": "^15.1.1"
  }
}
```

I'm at a loss as to why I get this error. I do not see any errors when I am building the production release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Move the "xmlbuilder": "^15.1.1" line to be inside the "dependencies"

Here is the updated package.json file

```
    {
  "name": "Title Of Program Here",
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "description": " ",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "package-mac": "electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/mac/icon.icns --prune=true --out=release-builds",
    "package-win": "electron-packager . electron-tutorial-app --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=assets/icons/win/icon.ico --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\" Title \"",
    "package-linux": "electron-packager . electron-tutorial-app --overwrite --asar=true --platform=linux --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/png/icon.png --prune=true --out=release-builds"
  },
  "author": "David Klecker",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "ejs": "^3.1.2",
    "electron": "^8.2.0",
    "electron-alert": "^0.1.5",
    "electron-reload": "^1.5.0",
    "embed-js": "^5.0.4",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jquery-treegrid": "^0.3.0",
    "php-server-manager": "^1.3.3",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "python-shell": "^1.0.8",
    "uniter": "^2.14.0",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.23",
    "xmlbuilder": "^15.1.1"

  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ejs-lint": "^1.1.0",
    "electron-packager": "^14.2.1"
  }
}
```

This eliminates the error. Not sure why xmlbuilder installs into package.json in this way but for those who use it, you will have to manually update your package.json file for this to be packaged correctly.